# How to programatically extract TCP/IP counters per TCP Connection?

Tags: linux, networking

In a past life I worked on a tool that was basically able to track this information:

src_ip, dst_ip, src_port, dst_port, bytes_sent, bytes_received, packets_sent, packets_received, packets_retransmitted, bytes_retransmitted

For every active TCP connection on the machine.  At the time (circa 2008) this relied on a kernel patch to extend the counters tracked by the kernel.  I thought I'd heard it was integrated into the kernel several years ago.  But its been forever and i'm forgetting the details.

Life has taken me full circle and I find myself wanting to write such a tool again, but I can't remember how to access these counters/configure linux so it tracks this information.

There might be some way to use netstat for this -- but I haven't been able to get the counter info exposed in that interface yet.

Any way to get the kernel to track this information -- and get the numbers exported reasonably efficiently would be sufficient.  Am hoping not to have to run IPTables to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some per-socket information through `/proc/net/tcp`. Other global information can be retried through `/proc/net/snmp`. However, I don't think that the kernel is tracking bytes_sent, bytes_received, packets_sent, packets_received, packets_retransmitted, bytes_retransmitted on a per-socket bases.

Comment: The closest to what i'm trying to do that i've found is something like:
http://code.google.com/p/ipt-account/wiki/Usage

But even this isn't exposing the retransmission values, which sadly is some of the most interesting information.  Looks like the patch I had previously used must have been part of something that was part of a customized kernel at a previous job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [linux conntrack](http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/manual.html) tool for flow statistics.

I guess that is the tool that you used before.